# How to add Another value in each loop handlebar js

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

```
<ul id="sortable">{{#each put.images}}
    <li class="imageSort" id="{{this}}">
      <div class="perant_edit_img">
      <span class="del_img_edit">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </span>
      <img src="/uploads/items/{{this}}" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

i need this value add in each {{put.dirImg}} put how ?

{{put.dirImg}} It is printed only outside the each but inside the each is can not printed!

Comment: What does `put` contain ?

Comment: but*************

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<ul id="sortable">
  {{#each put.images}}
    <li class="imageSort" id="{{this}}">
      <div class="perant_edit_img">
      <span class="del_img_edit">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </span>
      <img src="/uploads/items/{{../dirImg}}{{this}}" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: i need this {{put.dirImg}}  in src="/uploads/items/{{this.images}}" add here :

Comment: src="/uploads/items/{{put.dirImg}}{{this.images}}"

Comment: images is array and "dirImg" is single string

Comment: sorry but Your idea does not work on my code Did not work

Comment: Can you post a sample of the `put` variable contents ?

Comment: { endet_at: 'online', status: true, views: 2, gift: 'off', images: [ '1141529137-1536326198708.jpg', '4833188286-1536326200566.jpg', '6742466554-1536326202700.jpg' ], addFav: [XX], _id: 5b927a3e3d5e721c20dab568, title: 'test test test test test test', body: 'test test test test test test', street: 'XX', price: 0, oner: false, select_city: 'Alexandria', select_city_ar: 'XX', category: 'XX', sction: '1', dirImg: '5/', money: 'XX', cover: '5674695888-1536326206193_cov_.jpg', go: '104', vorschlag: [],slug: '5863373177-test-test-test-test-test-test' }

Comment: I have updated the solution above. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Fixed one more thing in the proposed solution above. See if that solves your issue.